# Get http referer URI from a view using twig

Tags: twig, symfony

I want to know in Twig from what URI the user came. For example:

1. The user is on the page /en/terms-of-use ('app_default_terms')
2. User clicks on login
3. On the register page is a hidden input to send the user back from where he came `<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ get_uri_from_where_he_came() }}" />`
4. He submits the form and is sent back.

My question is, what is the twig function for this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using symfony framework, you can access a special global variable `app` which hold the request among other attributes.

see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#global-template-variables

So you could use something like :

```
{% set referer = app.request.server.get('http-referer')|default('/') %}

<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ referer }}" />
```

Comment: Storing the target path on session is safer ; redirections like this on login pages might be used for fishing (like a fake website that tells you "Wrong password! Try again.." As the referer is a simple header, I won't rely on this as well.

Comment: Small detail : in Symfony 3.1 (probably 3.2?), it's not http-referer but HTTP_REFERER

Comment: the getter of the header bag normalizes it ;)

Comment: @AlainTiemblo See my comment on your answer about the problem with the session.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is a bit over-killing but ensures that you don't rely on arbitrary data coming from users.

### The idea

You always save the previous route on your application using an event listener; and you implement a `/reload` path that will send the user back to that route. On login success, you just have to redirect your user to that `/reload` path and you're good to go.

### The implementation

Change namespaces to fit with your application.

<kbd>LastRouteListener.php</kbd>

```
<?php

namespace Fuz\QuickStartBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException;
use Fuz\QuickStartBundle\Services\Routing;

class LastRouteListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $routing;

    public function __construct(Routing $routing)
    {
        $this->routing = $routing;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            $currentRoute = $this->routing->getCurrentRoute($request);
        } catch (ResourceNotFoundException $ex) {
            return;
        }
        if (is_null($currentRoute)) {
            return;
        }

        $session       = $request->getSession();
        $previousRoute = $session->get('current_route', array());
        if ($currentRoute == $previousRoute) {
            return;
        }

        $session->set('previous_route', $previousRoute);
        $session->set('current_route', $currentRoute);
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 15)),
        );
    }
}
```

<kbd>services.yml</kbd>

```
parameters:
    # ...
    quickstart.last_route.listener.class: Fuz\QuickStartBundle\EventListener\LastRouteListener

services:
    # ...

    quickstart.last_route.listener:
        class: %quickstart.last_route.listener.class%
        arguments: [@quickstart.routing]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

<kbd>ReloadController.php</kbd>

```
<?php

namespace Fuz\QuickStartBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Fuz\QuickStartBundle\Base\BaseController;

class ReloadController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * Get back to the previous route
     *
     * @Route("/reload", name="reload")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     */
    public function reloadAction(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->getSession()->has('previous_route')) {
            $route                      = $request->getSession()->get('previous_route');
            $route['params']['_locale'] = $request->getLocale();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($route['name'], $route['params']));
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home'));
    }
}
```

### Live

You can clone "symfony-quickstart" from my GitHub if you want to see this implementation live.

https://github.com/ninsuo/symfony-quickstart

Comment: Thanks for this idea, but I would desire to use the more simple form with the app variable. But thanks

Comment: The problem with storing that kind of thing in the session is that it breaks as soon as the user opens a link in another tab. For example once I opened 3 articles in tabs on a news web site, read the first one, commented, and after posting my comment, I was redirected to the third article instead of the one I commented on.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony 5.4

This worked for me.

```
app.request.headers.get('referer')
```